# Why does the character stream read ints?

Tags: java

In the example given in the [Oracle Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html) they are trying to read characters as integers... .

*Why and how does that work?*

```
try {
        inputStream = new FileReader("xanadu.txt");
        outputStream = new FileWriter("characteroutput.txt");

      int c;
      while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(c);
        }
```

Comment: ... Because virtually everything in a computer is numeric, and the numbers here just happen to correspond to character ordinals?

Comment: wow, thanks a lot for all of your fast answers! That helped me a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read char, there would be no value you could use for end of file.

By using a larger type `int`, its possible to have every possible character AND another symbol which means end of file.

Answer (score 0):

This is because characters ARE integers.  Each character has a unicode equivalent.

Comment: I think you are wrong. Characters (in Java) are shorter than integer as I know. Buut maybe i'm wrong. I'll check.

Comment: @Aslan986 chars are 16 bits, ints are 32

Answer (score 0):

Basically a `char` is an `int`. Try the following:

```
char c = 'c';
int i = c;
```

This will not cause a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes in java, a `char` is just a 16-bit unsigned value. An `int` is a 32-bit unsigned value.

`chars` are a subset of `ints` whose values have meaning on the ASCII tables.

Because of this relationship, it is a convenience for syntax to allow the two types to easily converted to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you read the documentation for `Reader`/`Writer` you can see the following explanation:

**Writer Class - write Method**

> Writes a single character.  The character to be written is contained
>   in  the 16 low-order bits of the given integer value; the 16
>   high-order bits  are ignored.

And the code simply does:

```
public void write(int c) throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (writeBuffer == null){
            writeBuffer = new char[writeBufferSize];
        }
        writeBuffer[0] = (char) c;
        write(writeBuffer, 0, 1);
    }
}
```

So, in the case of `Writer`, and as far as I can see this could have been done with a `char` data type.

The `Reader`, on the other hand, int its `read` method has the responsibility of returning a character or the end of the stream indicator.

The documentation says:

**Reader Class read Method**

> The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 
>   or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached.

As such, a data type bigger than just a char is needed, and in this case int is used.

And it is implemented as follows:

```
public int read() throws IOException {
    char cb[] = new char[1];
    if (read(cb, 0, 1) == -1)
        return -1;
    else
        return cb[0];
}
```

So, this second case justifies the use of a bigger data type.

The reason why they use an int in both classes could be just a matter of consistency.